# Changing the CSS on the Django admin page

Tags: django, templates, admin

I am trying to change the admin HTML templates but I don't really now how to find the already created Django templates in the first place.
Is there an easy way to find all the templates?

Right now I am making new html templates and extending them to Djangos templates.

Answer (score 0):

If you just look for an easy way to change the admin template you can use the *django-admin-interface*. You can change colors and it looks a bit more attractive. This works in my case pretty good.

```
pip install django-admin-interface
```

Comment: Can you add how exactly you would change the colors, etc. and perhaps a link to the documentation?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to find all the templates?

Yes, they're all in the `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin`. You should be able to find the top-level `django` directory in the `site-packages` directory where you installed your Python packages. For example, if you created a `.venv` directory, it could be in `.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`.

Otherwise, you could find the templates in the Github repository [here](https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin).

[The Django guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) recommends copying those templates over to your own `templates` directory.